# How to multiply two values of a same column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, multiplication

I want to multiply two different values of the same column.

Example:

```
Name  Values
A     10
B     5
C     2
```

I want to multiply values where Name = A and B. The result should be 50. How can I do that?

I used some multiply functions but they're not working.

Comment: How may values do you have for `A` and `B`? Can it be that `A` has 2 values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table is named "Table", then create a simple measure as follows and place it in a card:

```
Measure = CALCULATE( MAX('Table'[Values]),'Table'[Name] = "A") *  CALCULATE( MAX('Table'[Values]),'Table'[Name] = "B")
```